# Iframe send postMessage to parent in another domain

Tags: javascript

We have an iframe in a domain different from our main website.

This iframe consists of a form where we want to track some events from outside.

There are many web resources ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), [Matt West's Blog](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/cross-domain-messaging-with-postmessage)...) teaching how to send a postMessage for a window, but the path is always sending a message from the parent to the iframe/popup.

If the parent is at the same domain, it is possible to send the message as well, as pointed by [David Walsh](https://davidwalsh.name/window-iframe).

We need to send a message from the iframe to the parent.

Also, they are in different domains.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try it?

`parent.postMessage(message,'*')` works just fine across different domains, in all modern browsers.

The receiver's `message` handler should check the origin to make sure it's the domain they're expecting.

Comment: Hi geocar, that worked amazingly, thank you so much.